# C# WPF custom install location

Tags: c#

So the wizards of IT brilliantly put in to place new GPO that prevent access to the AppData folder structure in Windows for user PC's.  However, when you publish an application the application when installed is defaulting to C:\user\roaming\appdata, well the application can no longer access that directory.

How do I create a custom install path for the application to use?

Thanks!

Comment: what deployment strategy you are using ?

Comment: Incremental publish to a network directory

Comment: Have you attempted to explain the fact a user is suppose to be able to write to their AppData folder?  This is the folder Microsoft WANTS you to write application data to, it even suggests it, and will make default when appliciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does [this link about changing the InstallLocation attribute](http://www.hardcodet.net/2008/12/arpinstalllocation-for-visual-studio-setups) help?

Also keep in mind that user settings are stored in an AppData folder so if you use that you may need a workaround for that too.

Comment: Austin - to tell you the truth i've always kept this at default, i'm not postiive why on earth you would block that Folder structure, so this is new to me

Answer (score 0):

I would create a **Setup and Deployment** project to handle installation.  It is very easy to add using the **Setup Wizard** project template.  In this project you will be able to specify the default location of the application folder.

Answer (score 0):

My Assumption if you are using ClickOnce Deployment you can't define the installation path.
The idea of ClickOnce is making sure it doesn't require admin privileges to install the update therefore it kept under user app profile. There was [discussion here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/84b5ed72-2406-4518-97e7-f7c6cf7132a7)

if there is a reason to put you data and keep it safe from ClickOnce update.
refer to here [Keep data safe from ClickOnce deployment](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2009/08/19/where-do-i-put-my-data-to-keep-it-safe-from-clickonce-updates/)

another option as @Kevin mentioned create standalone MSI installer would allow you to specific the application install path however it would be manual intervention.

Personally I don't know why there is a need to prevent access to user AppData folder (perhaps re-define GPO to allow certain app folders access) could resolve that given if you want to continue using ClickOnce deployment